# Get the selected Node from a jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, jstree

I am trying to get the selected Node from a jstree.

This is the code in the View

```
<div id="divtree" >
    <ul id="tree" >
         @foreach (var m in Model.presidentList)
         {
             <li class="jstree-clicked">
                  <a href="#" class="usr">@m.Name</a>
                  @Html.Partial("Childrens", m)
              </li>
         }
     </ul>
</div>
```

This is the javascript part where I try to retrieve the name of the Node

```
$(".jstree-clicked").click(function (e) {
        var node = $(this).jstree('get_selected').text();
        alert(node);
});
```

I have a problem on getting only the selected node. If I select one of the children(last node of the tree for example) I still get the entire list of nodes.  Please let me know if you have any idea where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: According to jstree demo [here](http://www.jstree.com/demo) I don't see any similarities to your code for getting the clicked node or even setting up the tree.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you should assign class 'jstree-clicked' for each **<li>** node.
And get selected node using jstree container that you used for jstree binding.

```
console.log($("#divtree").jstree("get_selected").text());
```

Comment: Not working for me..

$(treeContainerId).jstree("get_selected");
["22~58", "22~59"]
$(treeContainerId).jstree("get_selected").text();
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You are allowing JSTree to selected multiple items it seems. Try using $(treeContainerId).jstree("get_selected")[0].text() or $(treeContainerId).jstree("get_selected")[1].text()

Comment: none of these work for me (: I wish there were a clear concise way to get a selected node.

Comment: It is not at all working. it is showing error as Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree(...).text is not a function

Comment: It will work if you add jstree and jquery files into your html and initialize jstree well.

Comment: @Murali Mopuru Ok can you tell me whats wrong with the code in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170283/how-to-get-selected-nodes-text-in-jstree

Comment: Thnx a lot, the api documentation is not clear at all on this subject. For someone else looking for it: $("#divtree").jstree("get_selected",true) will return the complete object

Comment: @MaartenKieft thanks! This should be a separate answer! Without 'true' it does not work for me.

Comment: @KjetilNordin: You're welcome. I converted it to answer :) I don't always check the comments either.

Answer (score 13):

`var data = $(yourtree).jstree().get_selected(true)[0].text;`

```
console.log(data);
```

This works for me. Give it a shot!

Comment: Works for me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Since more people found my comment useful I converted it to an answer. Thanks to the answer Murali, I was able to resolve my issue. This code:

```
$("#divtree").jstree("get_selected",true)
```

will return the complete object. (Look at the true parameter)

Comment: Related doc [here](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_selected([full]))

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var CurrentNode = $("#divtree").jstree("get_selected");
console.log($('#'+CurrentNode).text());
```

Comment: 1) This is wrong. No *<divtree>* element exists. 2) This looks like a poor copy and slight tweak of the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot "#"

Comment: You can also try this one -> $('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var i, j, r = [];
        for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
            r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
        }
        $('#resultText').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
    }).jstree();

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I create a new node in his 'selected' parent:

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="add_node">
            Add directory    
        </button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dir name" id="node_text">
</div>
```

And my Javascript :

```
    htmlSource.jstree();

    $('#add_node').on('click', function () {
        let text = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('#node_text').val();
        let selected = htmlSource.jstree('get_selected');
        htmlSource.jstree().create_node(selected, {
            "text": text
        },
        "last",
        function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    })
```

I hope it can be useful or give someone a lead

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#divtree").jsTree().get_selected(true)
```

will return an Array of the "node"