# How to get selected node's text in jstree

Tags: jstree

I have a jstree like shown below

[image]

and have the code in my script

```
$("#jstree").click(function (e) {
    var node = $("#jstree").jstree('get_selected');
    $('#resultText').html(node);
});
```

What i need is if i am selecting book, title, price i need to display output as **book-title-price**. By using above code i can get **id**s ie. 1-1_1-1_2 of my selected nodes but how can i get **text**s of the selected nodes in the above format?

COMPLETE CODE for jstree integration.

```
@model List<XMLNodeSearch.Models.NodeSearchModel>
<link href="~/vakata-jstree-8ea6ce7/dist/themes/default/style.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Script/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/vakata-jstree-8ea6ce7/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/vakata-jstree-8ea6ce7/dist/jstree.js"></script>

<script>
   $(function () {
   $('#jstree').jstree();
   $("#jstree").click(function (e) {
   var node = $("#jstree").jstree('get_selected').text();//This line with text() will throw an error
   $('#resultText').html(node);
  });
</script>

<section>
<label>Result - <span id="resultText"></span></label>
<div id="NodeResult">
    @if (Model != null)
    { 
        <div id="jstree">
            @foreach (var treeNode in Model)
            {
                <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
                <ul>
                    <li id="@treeNode.Id">@treeNode.NodeName
                        @if(treeNode.ChildNode.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var childNd in treeNode.ChildNode)
                                {
                                    <li id="@childNd.Id">@childNd.NodeName</li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problem. I am posting the answer here for anyone's future reference.

What i did is added the following script in my script block.

```
    $('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var i, j, r = [];
        for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
            r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
        }
        $('#resultText').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
    }).jstree();
```

This given me the desired output.

Answer (score 7):

Answer is a bit late, but thought will post anyways.

This will only get the id.

```
$('#tree_container').jstree('get_selected')
```

This should get the text.

```
$('#tree_container').jstree('get_selected', true)[0].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this way, if it works for you.

console.log($("#divtree").jstree("get_selected").text());

Comment: no i already tried it, but its not working. it is throwing error as Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree(...).text is not a function

Comment: This works, but if you have subnodes (child nodes) and these subnodes are open, then if you click on oldest ancestor node, it shows all text, including text from oldest node and all descendants nodes concatenated together. Rob's answer works better.